# Cannot get docker healthcheck to work with ECS Fargate v 1.4.0

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a health check defined for my ECS Fargate Service, it works when I test locally and works with Fargate v 1.3.0.

But when I change to Fargate Platform version 1.4.0 it always turns unhealthy. But the actual service is working. I can access the service on the containers public IP.

The health check is defined as:

```bash
"CMD-SHELL", "curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1"
```

Comment: can you inspect the container ? sometimes you get info why the healthceck fails. `docker container inspect CONTAINER --format '{{json .State.Health}}'`

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to inspect containers running in Fargate. And since 1.4.0 it does not even use docker anymore it is using containerd.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention, we are looking into why this is happening. I'll reply back when we have an answer for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So we looked into this and there's an issue in platform version 1.4 where, if the health check outputs anything to `stderr` a false negative occurs. We will, obviously, fix this but in the meantime you can work around this by (in this case) run curl in silent mode or simply redirect `stderr` output to /dev/null:

```
curl -s --fail http://localhost || exit 1
```

or

```
curl --fail http://localhost 2>/dev/null || exit 1
```

Should unblock you for now.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue and can confirm this workaround works for me on Fargate 1.4.0.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, an update has been released that addresses this. Tasks launched after 5/22 should no longer see this issue.

Comment: @MatsLannér I was having this issue just today and this workaround fixed it for me. The cluster, service, and tasks were all created in the last 3 weeks.

Comment: Aaron, can you please privately send me your AWS account id, region, and task ids. This should no longer be happening so I want to make sure we dig into this one and get to the bottom of it: mlanner (at) amazon.com. Thanks!

Comment: I experience the same issue with tasks that started in the last couple of days

Comment: Hey guys, I just wondered this problem has been fixed or not. Even though I set health check `CMD-SHELL, echo hello`, `Task failed container health checks` shown as a stopped reason with Fargate Platform Version 1.4.0. Should I get back to Platform Version 1.3.0 explicitely? All tasks and containers that I'm facing this problem are started at least on 2021-05-25, still happens now.

Comment: I found it still happens with 1.4.0. After change from 1.4.0 to 1.3.0 two days ago, everything works well.

Comment: I am able to run a healthy task without this workaround, beforehand I had been encountering the same error "Unhealthy" but for me, I found that the `nginx` image I was using `nginx:1.14` does not have the command `curl` packaged with it. Make sure first the same command will run successfully inside a similar container with same image you're using

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to collate some answers together and build on them, as follows.

I'm not being funny, but first and foremost make sure you have a healthcheck endpoint running somewhere. Note that this doesn't have to be inside your container! Let me show you what I mean:

```bash
curl -s --fail -I https://127.0.0.1:8000/ || exit 1
```

will only pass if you have a HTTP server running on localhost port 8000 (etc.). This can be anything that returns a 200 - over to you.

Tips:

0. Make sure curl is installed inside the container
1. `-s` is for silent
2. `--fail` - ask google
3. `-I` header only
4. If localhost doesn't work try 127.0.0.1

Now, in my case I was not running a HTTP server but rather a long-running python script. In its error state the script exits with 1 (which terminates the task), but otherwise (after a long time) it exits with 0. To fail the healthcheck, the healthcheck call must also return 0 (otherwise there is a 1 and the task is again terminated*). [*exit codes > 1 can be converted to a 1 - see below stolen trick.]

So I had to fake a different endpoint with the same behaviour.

Step forward, Google.

```bash
curl -s --fail -I https://www.google.com || exit 1
```

As before, but now hit an external endpoint kindly provided. Note the `|| exit 1` which converts any positive-definite integer exit code to the `1` liked by the healthcheck.

Sorry to "state the bleeding obvious", but you really do need a function running here - don't run curl on a local endpoint and expect to get a healthy status!

Remember to expose the https / http ports 443 / 80 in your docker file and in the JSON task definition spec/through the console UI.

TIP! Note that the `CMD-SHELL` syntax is slightly different depending.

Putting it all together, for ECS Fargate the rest is correct.

You could also try an `echo` rather than a `curl`. I am unclear whether a point-to-point call is even required.